# Select query returns nothing for a random number

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

I am trying to fetch values from the database where a certain random number has a match. Here is my line of code

```
echo $rand_number = $_POST['rand'];
$select = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from temp_info where rand_number = '$rand_number'");
```

I am successfully receiving the random number which is also saved in the database. When I want to fetch from the database using the mysqli_fetch_array command, it returns nothing. However, when I write the random number itself instead of the variable $random_number. The query returns the desired result.

I have double checked that the $rand_number has the same random number that is saved in the database. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And what does "returns nothing" mean? `$select` is empty? or `mysqli_num_rows($select)` returns integer 0?

Comment: Yes dear I know I have not yet dealt with the sql injection. Returns nothing means returns no results from the database. While the database has entities in the colum where rand_number = $rand_number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it might help :

```
$select = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from temp_info where rand_number ='".$rand_number."'");
```

Comment: Flat-out wrong. The query is a double-quoted string. The var WILL have been interpolated into the string.

Comment: rephrased answer, is this acceptable for you @MarcB ?

Comment: no, not really. changing how the variable gets added to the string is pointless. the generated string will be identical. `$x = "foo'" . $bar ."'baz"` v.s. `$x = "foo'$bar'baz"` work identically.

Answer (score 0):

could be the rand_number is stored in db like a number then try using  `rand_number = $rand_number`  without quotes

```
$select = mysqli_query($connection,"select * 
    from temp_info
    where rand_number = $rand_number");
```